# Trigger AWS WAF Rules XSS and SQL Injection

Tags: amazon-web-services, xss, amazon-waf

We created a new LB with a WAF based on some simple rules like block Scripting and SQL Injection, we read the owasp examplaes and the documentation of WAF. 
We are unable to trigger the Block of the request.

A simple examples like:

```
https://usite.com/index.php?name=%3Cscript%3Ewindow.onload%20=%20function()%20{var%20link=document.getElementsByTagName(%22a%22);link[0].href=%22http://not-real-xssattackexamples.com/%22;}%3C/script%3E
```

And:

```
 /?id=1+union+select+1,2,3/*
 index.php?id=1/*uni X on*/union/*sel X ect*/select+1,2,3/*
```

How can we trigger the block of the request scripts?